# I'm new to bundling tools. How and with which tool can I achieve this behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, bundle

Let's say I have the folder **/src/**. In there, there's an HTML file (and some scripts and stylesheets):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My website</h1>

        <script src="1.js">
        <script src="2.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

What's in the script and stylesheets doesn't matter, because this is just an example.

**Important:** This **/src/** folder is where I want to work in development. I don't want to go through the hassle of bundling/building stuff everytime I change any line of code in any of my files - I just want to save, reload the page, and see my results. Only when I'm ready for production do I want to create a bundle.

Now, let's say I *am* ready and I want to create a bundle to upload to my server, ready for public use. What I want in the end is this HTML file in a **/dist/** folder:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css_bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My website</h1>

        <script src="js_bundle.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

These CSS/JS bundle files should be compressed and minified. Building on this, it would be cool if I had the option to also minify my HTML, assuming there won't be any issues with missing whitespace characters:

```
<html><head><link href="css_bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><h1>My website</h1><script src="js_bundle.js"></body></html>
```

Bundling the JavaScript should also be able to take things like ES6 Modules into a count, as I use them regularly, but it should be optional. Enough browsers support modules natively these days, which makes me want to keep it "vanilla" instead of having to transpile it down to some ES5 polyfill.

I already checked out some webpack docs, but found the "Quick Guide" didn't match my needs. **Which tools can achieve such behavior?**

Comment: You can use webpack only in production. See e.g. https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/managing-dev-and-production-builds-webpack for some guidance on how to go about doing so.

Comment: @Hector Uff. Thanks for now.